# Hamaor Hagadol vs Hakatan (books)

Tags: names, jewish-books

[R. Zerachiah ha-Levi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zerachiah_ha-Levi_of_Girona) composed a comentary on Rif, named "Sefer Hamaor".

Why is it split into "Hamaor Hagadol" (on Noshim and Nezikin) and "Hamaor Hakatan" (on Zroim, Mo'ed and Chullin).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rav Zerachia HaLevi writes in his introduction to the work ([here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40787&st=&pgnum=3)) that he named the section on Nashim and Nezikin "Maor HaGadol" because these sections are known as the Great Work in the Torah (referencing [BB 175b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=175b&format=pdf)). He named the section dealing with Moed "Maor Katan" (a reference to the moon) because Moed deals with the holidays which are determined by the lunar months. Chulin and Brachot were attached with Moed because it is the smaller half.

Comment: quote from BB 175B: _"R' Yishmael said, one who wishes to become wise should occupy himself with monetary law, for there are no stores greater than them, and they are like a gushing spring."_